# Ignore flake8 warning in SublimeLinter

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, flake8, sublimelinter

I have installed [SublimeLinter-flake8](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-flake8#sublimelinter-flake8). I would like to exclude the [W191](https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/W191.html) warning when I am using SublimeLinter with `flake8`. I have checked the SublimeLinter [docs](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/linter_settings.html#args) and tried adding `"--ignore W191"` to my user settings file and reloaded plugins but I still get warned about the usage of tabs.

The following is my `Packages/User/SublimeLinter.sublime-settings` file.

```
// SublimeLinter Settings - User
{
    "linters": {
        "linter_name" : {
            "args" : "--ignore W191"
        }
    }
}
```

I checked [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60690222/how-can-i-change-indentation-settings-for-flake8-in-sublime-text) but I would like it to be applied from the settings file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `linter_name` has to be the specific plugin you're looking to configure (in this case `flake8`) -- try this:

```json
{
    "linters": {
        "flake8" : {
            "args" : "--ignore W191"
        }
    }
}
```

though realistically, it is probably better to configure your flake8 settings in [flake8's configuration](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html#project-configuration) such that contributors to your project can work on your project without your specific sublimetext settings.  I believe sublimetext's invocation of flake8 should be compatible with those configurations if I'm reading their code correctly

---

disclaimer: though I'm not sure it's super relevant here, I currently maintain flake8

Comment: thank you so much, this worked, I will try to configure my settings in flake8 if its considered best practice

Comment: When using with `black` it's better to use `--extend-ignore` instead of `--ignore` because the latter overrides the ignore list and re-enables errors which were disabled for `black`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68172142