# Python black formatter conflict with rule flake8 W503 in VSCode

Tags: python, flake8, python-black

Anytime there is an inline assertion rule to be verified against a bool statement, using the python black formatter in VSCode will break the line causing flake8 to warn about rule W503

```
line break before binary operatorflake8(W503)

assert (
      ...
      != ...
)
```

Is there any fix for this rather than ignoring that rule?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

you have set `ignore =` in your configuration -- you should use `extend-ignore =`

`W504` and `W503` conflict with each other (and are both disabled by default) -- by setting `ignore` you've re-enabled them. `extend-ignore` does not have this problem as it augments the default set of ignored codes

note that when working with black you'll want to use black's recommended settings: https://github.com/psf/black/blob/06ccb88bf2bd35a4dc5d591bb296b5b299d07323/docs/guides/using_black_with_other_tools.md#flake8

```
max-line-length = 88
extend-ignore = E203
```

---

disclaimer: I'm the current flake8 maintainer

Comment: it also detects rule E501 and run the linter on the file doesn't solve it

Comment: then add that to extend-ignore too (though the `max-line-length` is supposed to cover that)

Comment: Ah! I was looking for answer why I keep seeing W503 even with the latest flake8/pycodestyle - and it was all about the fact that `ignore` setting resets the default ignore list, which W503 is in. Thanks!